# How do I return JSON from SQL SERVER 2016 using a return value as a JSON key?

Tags: sql-server, json

I have the following table structure

```
╔══════════════════════╦═══════╦══════════════════════╗
║         key          ║ lang  ║         text         ║
╠══════════════════════╬═══════╬══════════════════════╣
║ epost.leder.lykketil ║ nn-NO ║ Lykke til!           ║
║ epost.leder.lykketil ║ de-DE ║ Viel Erfolg!         ║
║ epost.leder.lykketil ║ pl-PL ║ Powodzenia!          ║
║ epost.leder.lykketil ║ en-US ║ Good luck!           ║
║ epost.leder.lykketil ║ sv-SE ║ Lycka till!          ║
║ epost.leder.lykketil ║ da-DK ║ God fornøjelse!      ║
║ epost.leder.lykketil ║ lt-LT ║ Sėkmės!              ║
║ epost.leder.lykketil ║ lv-LV ║ Labu veiksmi!        ║
║ epost.leder.lykketil ║ et-EE ║ Õnn kaasa!           ║
║ epost.leder.lykketil ║ nb-NO ║ Lykke til!           ║
║ lp.aggregertrapport  ║ pl-PL ║ Zagregowany raport   ║
║ lp.aggregertrapport  ║ nn-NO ║ Aggregert rapport    ║
║ lp.aggregertrapport  ║ de-DE ║ Aggregierter Bericht ║
║ lp.aggregertrapport  ║ sv-SE ║ Aggregerad rapport   ║
║ lp.aggregertrapport  ║ en-US ║ Aggregated report    ║
║ lp.aggregertrapport  ║ da-DK ║ Samlet rapport       ║
╚══════════════════════╩═══════╩══════════════════════╝
```

And I want the following structure

```
[{
  "key": "epost.leder.lykketil",
  "text": {
    "nn-NO": "Lykke til!",
    "de-DE": "Viel Erfolg!",
    "pl-PL": "Powodzenia!",
    "en-US": "Good luck!",
    ...
    "nb-NO": "Lykke til!"
  }
},
{
  "key": "lp.aggregertrapport",
  ...
}]
```

I have tried several solutions using the `SELECT FOR JSON` functionality in SQL Server 2016, but I can't figure out how to use a return-value as a key.

Comment: Show your query so far - what you have tried, and explain why it's wrong.

Comment: I'll see what I can do... I've deleted everything as I've been going. But mostly it's resulted in one json object for each line in the table. I can't figure out the grouping, and I can't figure out the value as key part.

Comment: Did you find any way doing it? @ChristianWattengård

Comment: I ended up using LINQPad to generate the structure and JSON.net to dump it to a text-file :) My goal was to transfer some translations of the system I'm currently building to a new DB-system (DocumentDB)